# How to change language programmatically in swift 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift2

I have app that has 2 languages and I want to choose between languages programmatically in swift .. how can I do it in code ?

Comment: Will you explain a bit more?

Comment: I think he means he wants to localize his app between two languages, like English and Spanish, for example.

Comment: If you are trying to change language at runtime I suggest you to don't do it. Even if you are able to do with some tricks, most of system service stay put with device language. For instance Map visualization will show streets names using device language.

Comment: @Aisha I mean my app localized in 2 languages arabic and english when user click language button i want the app is changed to selected language I visualise my storyboard to these languages when i click the button it's still in the same state until i restart the app .. is there a way to change without restarting? thanks and respect

Comment: Are you using table to view to show the languages?

Comment: @Andrea i need to do it at runtime like in android but in iOS must restart the app

Comment: @Aisha not table but i have a button to select preferred language

Comment: What happens when you change the language?

Comment: @Aisha All labels still the same beside some times when I run for first time labels still in english and data from json in arabic

Comment: Ok so where you are setting the labels values. Will you remain on the same view controller? Or it is pushing to another view?

Comment: in fact I set it Programmatically or you can call it manually :) ,, I use flag to determine which language is selected then i set the labels ... static labels i use Xcode localisation for it

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting them manually then you just have to set that label value in button click action. It just needs reload of data.

Comment: Its okay. Anytime